# Replace server JSON response in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a problem with some web-based tool that queries a server for JSON data in the AJAX way. It's not working properly - returned results are often not what I want and I need to **wait a lot of time** for the server to process the request.

The truth is I always want the same data (about a few people, to be precise) returned, so I thought of faking the server response. I tried to achieve this in a few ways, but didn't succeed.

I tried using Chrome's WebRequest functionality - I prepared an extension and redirected the request to a data URL with my JSON encoded. It worked, but only when I entered address manually in the Chrome's address field. When the web app tried to access the address, redirect silently failed. I immediately thought of Access Origin restrictions and quickly set up a webserver sending Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers.

Unfortunately, this didn't work too. When I entered the address by hand, the server was being queried and returned the right JSON, but in the app the request... silently failed. It looked like Chrome totally ignored possible Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers, since it didn't even queried the server. It's quite possible that Chrome only analyzes URLs since when I redirected the problematic request to random URL in app's domain it worked.

I also tried faking the whole JavaScript file of the app - which is statically linked to a document (e.g. it's included via standard script tag) using the same method. I failed miserably - the redirection just silently failed like it was failing on my first attempts.

A common solution to my problem is to use some kind of a proxy which changes server output, but I can't do that - I don't want to wait a few minutes for server to process the request. And by the way, the app is accessible only via HTTPS.

Is there any other way to feed the app with my hardcoded JSON? Or maybe I'm missing something?

**EDIT**
Plugin code, based on "catblock" example:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
function(info) {
  console.log("AJAX call intercepted: " + info.url)
  return {redirectUrl: 'data:application/json,"test"'};
},
// filters
{
  urls: [
  "*://address.to.the.js.file.requested"
]
}, ['blocking']);
```

Manifest file, I only added the domain to the permissions section:

```
{
"name": "CatBlock",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "I can't has cheezburger!",
"permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", 
              "*://some.domain.com/*"],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"manifest_version": 2
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Here are the screenshots from network panel of Chrome's developer Console which show that request gets silently canceled:
[image: Console screenshot]
[image: Console screenshot]

Comment: "I tried using Chrome's WebRequest functionality" - Did you add "xmlhttprequest" to the filter? Show your current allegedly broken extension.

Comment: @RobW: I added the code, sorry for the delay - I couldn't answer your request faster.

Comment: Your request fails because of the Same origin policy (in Chrome, `data:` is considered a different origin). You have to access a http(s) resource and append CORS headers to the response.

Comment: @RobW: I came up with this solution, and I as mentioned in my question - it didn't work. Chrome didn't even made a request to my HTTP server when app requested the JSON. To be clear - when I entered the address manually, everything worked great. I think it has something to do with Same origin policy, but Chrome internally assumes that it should cancel the request without even looking at returned headers.

Comment: When you use `redirectUrl` with a resource from a different origin, the request is canceled. Did you add [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors) response headers, as I mentioned in my previous comment? (To do a quick test, append `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`).

Comment: @RobW: Yes, and I as said - I tried this before. I set up Python SimpleHTTPServer, tweaked it to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, placed file with JSON in the right place and changed redirectUrl parameter. When I navigated to the to-be-redirected URL in Chrome, server responded and Chrome showed me the file. That works. When I opened the app, the app's request was immediately cancelled inside Chrome. The server showed no activity whatsoever. And that is the problem the question is about.

Comment: @user1234567 do you know the place from where the AJAX call is being made. Cant you modify the js and placed mocked up object in the response .. i guess this way you have to modify the page every time using google developer tools

Comment: @user1428716: Yes, but as you said - I'd need to modify page manually every time.

Comment: We just encountered the same problem. Have you found the solution yet? or have you filed a bug report to Chromium's team yet?

Comment: @zhuzhuor: None of that.

Comment: @user1234567 I found the problem even exists when the xhr is redirected by the server itself. I filed a bug report at http://crbug.com/244109. You can star it if you are interested.

Answer (score 3):

There are couple ways to do this.

The most easy way is to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)
If you know Russian, or your browser has a decent translate feature, you can read this [article](http://habrahabr.ru/post/140147/) - as I understand in your case you need second part - about Autoresponder.
Or below there is few links with manuals in english.

this screenshot is the answer [image]

About Access-Control-Allow-Origin in chrome - also my [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) is's totaly simple (just add to response headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *") and allow you aviod this error when you develop some feature. You can do same thing with Fiddler
also In chrome you can run Chrome with developer key "chrome --disable-web-security"
it is also remove error of "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Comment: The problem is not directly connected with Access-Control-Allow-Origin. It's rather some built-in mechanism that rejects the redirection without even trying to check the headers. Even disabling web security doesn't disable that. Fiddler will do the job, but I would like a solution based on Chrome extension. Since the app is served exclusively via HTTPS I will need to setup Fiddler to do the MiM attack and since I'd like to use that on a daily basis and not just for testing, I'd like to refrain from that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, *you* are in control of the server that generates the JSON response.
If that's the case then it must be possible - *without* any Chrome extension - to get the AJAX (XMLHTTPRequest) request and response working with the correct CORS headers.

As per my experience, failed cross-domain XHR requests only *seem* to fail "silently" in Chrome, but if you have a closer look at the console you will see an error message *similar* to:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/yourJSONfile.json. Origin http://your-app-domain.com:80 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

This message may sometimes be misleading, because it will show up if *anything* CORS related went wrong (even if the Access-Control-Allow-Origin was set correctly).
Also, on the network tab you will see the XHR request and response headers.

Now lets talk about the CORS headers. I would have to see your request's AJAX options or HTTP request headers to tell exactly which CORS headers you need, but as far as I can tell right now "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" might not be sufficient for your request to succeed:
Depending on your request headers (which I'm unaware of at the moment, so the following are just examples), you might need additional CORS headers like:

> "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS, GET, POST"
>
> "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "content-type, accept, origin"

Also, for debugging purpose, it will be helpful to enable:

> "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

so that you can see the CORS related response headers on the network tab.

Comment: Well, I'm not in the control of the original server, but I'm in the control of some other server which can send altered data. The problem is, that the request doesn't just seem to fail silently. It really fails silently. There's no error in the console - only a misleading warning `The page at "https://the.app.com displayed insecure content from http://.../my.json"`, but Chrome doesn't even make request to server hosting my.json file. I updated my question with screenshots from dev console.

Comment: Can the server controlled by you receive the correct data from the original server?

Comment: So, then you can setup a proxy on your server and cache responses from remote one. This would greatly reduce the delay that you have now when you send requests to the remote server. Your script would send requests to your server, if the cache is present it is immediately returned to the script, if not the request is forwarded to the remote server and when the response is arrived it is cached and forwarded back to your script.

Comment: @user1234567, you mentioned that the end product is a web based tool. That leads me to the suggestion that you abandon Chrome's webrequest extension and instead focus on troubleshooting the XHR that gets triggered by the javascript code within the web based tool.
Then, when you inspect the headers like I suggested in my answer, you'll have a good chance to get the CORS response headers set right. An important step within the troubleshooting will be exposing the response headers by specifying "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Comment: @bancer: Yes, but that still leaves the problem open. marty -  I fully understand your point - but you are making the assumption that Chrome *sends* the request to my server when app requests the JSON. My problem is that Chrome sends 0 (zero) bytes in total to the server. I've verified this statement using both wireshark and additionally by using netcat in listen mode as a fake server.